# Real-time moving overlay over HTML5 video

Tags: css, html, html5-canvas, html5-video

I'm planning to implement an overlay over an normal HTML5 video. The key requirements about this overlay are: 
- Its location changes every second, and its exact location is read from a local JSON (or similar) file once every second. (The JSON file's content is updated by a different local program)
- It can be a simple shape, such as a square or a circle. 
- There is no interaction involved with it. 

I tried searching through lots of solutions but most of the overlay solutions I found online are either static or irrelevant to third-party data source (like local JSON file). Any advice on where should I begin is appreciated.

Comment: How does the json file look like? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Huelfe the json file simply states the x and y coordinates of the centre of the overlay shape - nothing else. By searching I think 
the "popcorn" plugin looks similar to what I want [link]http://brianchirls.github.io/popcorn-base/examples/ but I don't know how to import & dynamically update the specific locations of the overlay.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts I'd love to, but I don't even know where to begin yet. I haven't been able to identify an existing answer that can get me started.

Comment: So if you have the coordinates, you could easily add a absolute positioned div for the overlay and set `top` and `left` attribute relative to the video. To center your overlay just use `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)`.

Comment: @Huelfe thanks for the pointer, after adding the div I will then try using a JavaScript function to dynamically adjust the div's location. I hope this will work?

Comment: If you post some code here I could help you. But yeah I think this will work.

Comment: @Huelfe thanks a lot, it's all working now!

Comment: You're welcome @Chang :)